# magic file capable of detecting file types

Tags: files, manpage

how to make a magic file called ft_magic that will be formatted appropriately to detect
files of 42 file type, built with a "42" string at the 42nd byte.

i tried to make a ft_magic file using file -C -m ft_magic then file -m ft_magic

then i get this :

Usage: file [-bcCdEhikLlNnprsSvzZ0] [--apple] [--extension] [--mime-encoding]
[--mime-type] [-e ] [-F ]  [-f ]
[-m ] [-P <parameter=value>]  ...
file -C [-m ]
file [--help]

Comment: This means `ft_magic ` is either empty or not following the right format ... you need to populate it before compiling and using it ... Please see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/magic.5.html for the format.